# SendGrid Parse Inbound email from multiple domains

Tags: email, parsing, sendgrid, multiple-domains, inbound

Currently I'm thinking to work with [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/) and I have an issue.

I want to Know if I can parse incoming emails from multiple domains.

I read the documentation from [Parse Webhook Settings](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/parse_settings.html#-set), and I only see just one domain.

So, is there a way to receive from multiple domains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can pretty much have as many domains as you'd like. You can do that by [adding multiple hosts](https://www.evernote.com/l/AMBQAgrw6flPPJSrhqYfs9Nb8lsIHHzLPV4). My example has different hosts on the same domain, but you can have different domains there.

Comment: Another thing! If I want to use a regular expression in the domain like [0-9]@mail.com can i do it?

Comment: No, it has to be explicit domains, though you can use `*.domain.com`, as long as you have the MX record pointing to SendGrid.